# Retornar Valor de Select

Tags: codeigniter

Olá, 
Gostaria de saber como recuperar um resultado de um select no Controller para realizar uma soma de variáveis.
Eu tenho dois selects que preciso do valor resultante deles para somar dentro do Controller.

```
    // A = select total ja proposto
    $this->db->select('SUM(tb_proposicao.valor) as totalproposto');
    $this->db->where('tb_proposicao.usuarioid', 1;
    $this->db->where('tb_proposicao.tipoid', 1;
    $dados['totalproposto'] = $this->db->get('tb_proposicao')->result();


    // B = select limite
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('tb_limites.usuarioid', 1;
    $this->db->where('tb_limites.tipoid', 1;
    $dados['limites'] = = $this->db->get('tb_limites')->result(); 

    $A + $B = $C
```

Comment: Não entendi, qual o erro? Select você se refere a Query SQL?

Answer (score 0):

`$A = $this->db
          ->select('SUM(tb_proposicao.valor) as totalproposto')
          ->where('tb_proposicao.usuarioid', 1)
          ->where('tb_proposicao.tipoid', 1)
          ->get('tb_proposicao')->row();`

O row(), me rornará somente uma coluna objeto

Para cálculos a "B" retornará a tabela inteira, chuto que será um count.

`$B = $this->db
          ->select('count(*) as limite')
          ->where('tb_limites.usuarioid', 1)
          ->where('tb_limites.tipoid', 1)
          ->get('tb_limites')->row();`

Tendo os dois objetos basta soma os valores
É interessante informar os tipos de dados retornados, se float, double, int.. para cálculos.


`$C = floatval($A->totalproposto) + intval($B->limite);`